# Get days hours minutes from timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, timestamp

How to get days, hours, minutes with javascript(jquery) before some period at future.

Etc. I have timestamp: 1457136000000

How I can find how many days, hours and minutes is until 1457136000000 ?

Comment: Have a look at the Date methods : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Did my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Moment.js library and the [diff method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/):

```
var a = moment(1457136000000);
var b = moment(); // gets current time
var diff = a.diff(b); //2156483196
```

`diff` contains the difference in unix time, you can convert it to any format you like now.